# Animating the resize of a UIView that has subviews

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview, uiviewanimation

I've got a UIView that has a UITableView subview.

The UIView is a menu, that initially has the width of 50% of the device width, and the UITableView has AutoLayout constraints to the UIView.

Selecting an item in the menu triggers the UIView to resize to 33% of the device width. The UITableView, as I expected, changes size without animation, and then the UIView catches up with it via an animation.

Is there any easy way to animate my UITableView with my UIView, whilst maintaining AutoLayout constraints?

I've tried the following, inside the same animation block as the UIView:

```
let tableWidth = self.mm.menuOneController.tableView.bounds.size.width
let newTableWidth = (tableWidth * 2) / 3
self.mm.menuOneController.tableView.bounds.size.width = newTableWidth
```

This works, the UITableView is resizing with animation along with the UIView, however the AutoLayout doesn't quite work as I'd expect.

The UIView's X value is 0.0, so it's pinned to the left of the superview, and when it resizes, it does so from it's right hand size. However, the UITableView seems to resize equally on both left and right until it reaches the correct width (I hope that makes sense).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provided that constraints are not unambiguous at each state, and you have adjusted the constraints of the final animation state, a simple `layoutIfNeeded()` (on their common superview) inside `UIView.animate...` would do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lose the three lines you listed in your question from the animation block and at the end of the block add a call to `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view that is changing size. (i.e. `<yourMenuView>.layoutIfNeeded()`)

This causes the constraints to be re-applied in each animation frame adjusting the layout of all the subviews as needed to comply with the constraints.

Comment: This did work, however it seems that it's now only working on the 2nd time of asking. So, I add the subview for the first time and the layoutIfNeeded is definitely doing something, it's not doing the same that as it does _after_ the first time, at which point it's doing what is expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, you said lose the three lines? But those lines determine where my views will end up, and animate to. So I can't lose them?

Comment: As long as the constraints are all hooked up between the menu view and the table view you only need to resize the menu view itself and the table view will get drug along for the ride. I'm not sure how you control the width of the menu view currently but I would recommend using a constraint and changing the constant or multiplier (I forget if the multiplier is animatable or not). Otherwise you end up with auto layout and direct frame manipulation possibly conflicting with one another.